css doesn't apply on a page but apply to others
I'm following a course and I'm building this web site where I'm using ejs .
I'm encountering 2 problems, first this page doesn't show and keeps loading until I stop the loading
Second when it loads there's no css even though I included the header and footer but it applies on the other pages
note that this is how I called the page
    app.get("/posts/:title", function(req, res) {
      const requestedTitle=_.lowerCase(req.params.title);
      posts.forEach(function(post){
        const storedTitle=_.lowerCase(post.title)
        if (requestedTitle == storedTitle) {
          res.render("posts",{title:post.title,text:post.text});
                                          }})}) 


this the page in question :

    <%- include ('partials/header');-%>
    
    
     <h1><%= title %></h1>
    
     <p> <%= text %> </p>
    
     <%- include('partials/footer');-%>


and here's my header :

    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>Daily Journal</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <p class="navbar-brand">DAILY JOURNAL</p>
          </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <!-- 6 -->
              <li id="home"><a href="/">HOME</a></li>
              <li id="about"><a href="/about">ABOUT US</a></li>
              <li id="contact"><a href="/contact">CONTACT US</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    
      <body>
        <div class="container">



Your HTML Markup is invalid. head is for meta-information about the document its not to be mistaken with the header for stuff to be visually placed at the top. nav is not allowed to be a child element within the head. Your Paragraph is also not content for the nav but actually a headline ( h1) within the header while nav can be a child of the header.

thanx i fixed thes issues but i still have the same problem

Then please correct the code you have provided in a proper [mcve]. Use the <> icon to create a snippet.

What is the URL of the page in which your CSS "works", and what one of those in which it doesn't? I am suspecting this is simply the common issue of the relative stylesheet URL not resolving correctly, because the "folder depth" (number of folders in the URL path) is different. Usually the easiest solution - refer it from the domain root, by starting the URL with a slash: /styles.css

Is it possible that you have a redirect loop perchance?

thank you guys i fixed the issue it was a problem with the relative stylesheet url like even tho it worked with the other pages

possible reviews:

make sure you imported lodash
closing tag is wrong: no dash at end <%- include('partials/header') %>
your <header> is actually on <head> tag, fix it (check below).
check you paths, filenames and routes

HTML DOM example:
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
    </header>
    ...
  </body>
</html>

if those solve your request, please mark it as answer, if not, please share your output log, there you can find many answers on what is going on.

thank you i fixed the problem
it was an issue with the relative stylesheet URL
